# Ajax call to php script fails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem that I've been trying to deal with for the past couple of days. And it is starting to annoy me..
I can't seem to make my AJAX call work. I have a simple form and I'm trying to send the parameters to a php script, but it keeps giving me an error.

```
  $("#submitRSS").click(function() {

        var newspaper_id = $("#aviser").find('option:selected').attr("newspaper_id");
        var kategori_id = $("#kategorier").find('option:selected').attr("category_id");
        var url = $("#urlRSS").val();
        var content = $("#contentRSS").val();
        var image = $("#imageRSS").val();

        $.ajax({
                url:'insert_crawler_RSS.php',
                type:'GET',
                data:{'newspaper_id':newspaper_id,'kategori_id':kategori_id,'url':url,'content':content,'image':image},

                success: function (res) {
                    $("#message").append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Godt arbejde!</div>');
                },
                error: function() {
                    //$("#message").append('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Noget gik galt :(</div>');
                    alert("error");
                }

        });

    });
```

And this is insert_crawler_RSS.php:

```
    if(isset($_GET['newspaper_id'])) {
        $newspaper_id = $_GET['newspaper_id'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['kategori_id'])) {
        $category_id = $_GET['kategori_id'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $url = $_GET['url'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['content'])) {
        $content = $_GET['content'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['image'])) {
        $image = $_GET['image'];
    }

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO crawler_urls (url,newspaper_id,rss,category_id) VALUES('$url','$newspaper_id','1','$category_id')");
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO crawlers (content_xpath,newspaper_id,image_xpath) VALUES('$content','$newspaper_id','$image')");
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? Please help me. I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: What error do you have? What does developer console say?

Comment: if this is a form you aren't preventing the default browser submit, use `preventDefault()` or return `false`

Comment: exactly charlieftl! that solved my problem! :) thanks a lot - how do I accept your answer?

Answer (score -1):

1. Try putting the full url starting from the http://...
2. You don't need to put `''` inside the data part. You can do it like:

   data:{newspaper_id:newspaper_id,kategori_id:kategori_id,url:url,content:content,image:image}
3. For debugging; change your error function to :

   error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
   alert(xhr + "," + textstatus + "," + errorThrown);}

so you can see what is wrong with your code.

Comment: OP is using $_GET at server so setting ajax type to `'post`` makes no sense and will certainly fail

Comment: Didn't know that works that way in PHP, edited the post.

Comment: Hi Emre.Your suggestions didn't solve my problem, unfortunately:( The error function you mentioned doesn't alert anything